# Gerar checkbox no Datatable por sDefaultContent com IDs diferentes

Tags: jquery-datatables, datatable

Estou gerando um checkbox para cada linha do DataTable através de sDefaultContent, mas quando realizo uma ação em um dos checkbox, este replica para todos os outros. Estou com dificuldade para gerar um checkbox com ID diferente para cada linha.

Segue código atual:

```
"aoColumnDefs" : [
            //adiciona a classe para todas as células referente a coluna indicada
            {"sClass" : "hidden-xs sorting","aTargets" : [1]},              
            {"sClass" : "alignbutton","mData": "", "sDefaultContent": "<input type='checkbox'  name='ckbPremiacao' class='ckbPremiacao' style='text-align:center'  onchange='alteraPremiacao()' ></input><script>$('.ckbPremiacao').bootstrapSwitch();</script>","aTargets": [3]}
        ]
```

Alguém sabe como me ajudar? [URGENTE]

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo usar o [createdRow](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow), ele é executado a cada `tr` criada. Assim você conseguirá atribuir os eventos e até usar o `bootstrapSwitch` na linha específica.

Talvez combinar esta abordagem com o [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) possa ter alguma utilidade, pois também tem acesso aos dados da linha, consequentemente sendo possível gerar um id para o checkbox.